# customize right click context menu of linux file or folder using java

Tags: java, linux, filesystems, contextmenu, filetable

I want to run two `java` application in the sense. When first application executes, it first create a file or folder having only two right click context menu option.

1. Mount
2. Unmount

   - When user click on Unmount file or folder  will delete
   - When user click on Mount file or folder will execute  second `java` application.

**In Short**

How to customize the linux file right click context menu and listen its event also.

Comment: Seems a little confusing. A bash file with right click context menu?

Comment: Sorry , it can be any file or folder .